Querying Cassandra from SQL server with where clause issue
I'm facing a strange issue where I have a SQL server connected to Cassandra to pull time series data. I'm using the 'DataStax C/C++ Driver for Apache Cassandra' and have connected via a 'linked' server.
I can do basic queries like 'select top 10 from [schema].[table]' and it returns instantly, however, if I query with a select making sure I use the columns using indexes, it hangs indefinitely. I can run the same query via cqlsh and it returns fine.
I tried to trace the network to see what query was created from SQL server in case there is a problem there, but I can't see anything wrong with it.
Any ideas?
Cassandra 3.11.6
SQL server 2019
Cheers,
Thomas
update [add schema and query]:
CREATE TABLE ss.reading (
    sourceid bigint,
    sourcetype text,
    timestamp bigint,
    data text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((sourceid, sourcetype), timestamp)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (timestamp DESC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';

and query:
cqlsh:ss> select * from reading where sourceid = 21 and sourcetype = 'FEED'  and timestamp > 0  limit 10;

 sourceid | sourcetype | timestamp     | data
----------+------------+---------------+--------
       21 |       FEED | 1598562898981 | 13.591
       21 |       FEED | 1598559216193 | 13.483
       21 |       FEED | 1598555530849 | 13.375
       21 |       FEED | 1598551831551 | 13.268
       21 |       FEED | 1598548150751 | 13.052
       21 |       FEED | 1598544465888 | 12.837
       21 |       FEED | 1598540761730 | 12.729
       21 |       FEED | 1598537080073 | 12.514
       21 |       FEED | 1598533382058 | 12.406
       21 |       FEED | 1598529695090 | 12.084

(10 rows)


Welcome to Stack Exchange! Your question is missing some crucial details. Please update your question with (1) the table's CQL schema, and (2) the CQL query. Cheers!

Thanks Erick, have added them now :) @ErickRamirez

It looks like you are unnecessarily filtering on the clustering column timestamp. By definition, the column will always have a non-zero value so there is no need to do a range query.
When you query the table using the full partition key (sourceid, sourcetype), it is sufficient to retrieve the rows in the partition:
SELECT * FROM reading
  WHERE sourceid = ?
  AND sourcetype = ?
  LIMIT 10

This query will retrieve the 10 "latest" rows (since timestamp is sorted in DESC order).
If you weren't already aware, you can also page through the results without having to use the LIMIT clause. For details, see Handling results with the C++ driver. Cheers!
